# Criar uma função que leia uma lista corretamente

Tags: python, funções, lista

Esta função deverá pedir um nome para ser usado como termo de busca.
Se o filme buscado estiver na lista, deverão ser mostrados todos os dados do
filme. Senão, deverá ser mostrado uma mensagem de que não consta na lista.

Essa é a função que eu criei para tentar resolver a questão mas ela apresenta algumas falhas que cito abaixo:

```
def funçao2(n):
    arq = open('ListaFilmes.txt', 'r')
    conteudo = arq.readlines()
    arq.close()

    n = str(input('Digite o nome do filme: '))

    for linha in conteudo:
        linha = linha.split(';')
        for coluna in linha:
            coluna = coluna.split()
            coluna1 = linha[0]
            coluna2 = linha[1]
            coluna3 = linha[2]
            coluna4 = linha[3]
            for elem in coluna:
                if n == elem:
                    print('NOME:',coluna1)
                    print('GÊNERO:',coluna2)
                    print('CLASSIFICAÇÃO:',coluna3)
                    print('ANO DE LANÇAMENTO:',coluna4)
                else:
                    print('O filme não consta na lista')
```

Desse modo que eu criei, se por exemplo eu quero acessar um filme que conste na lista, ele acessa o filme, mas também mostra a mensagem 'O filme não consta na lista', mensagem esta que só é pra acontecer caso eu tente procurar por um filme que não consta na lista, e quando eu vou procurar um filme que não consta na lista, esta mensagem aparece várias vezes.

Vocês podem me ajudar a ajeitar o código para que caso eu pesquise o filme que consta na lista, o programa mostre apenas o filme pesquisado, e caso eu procure um filme que não consta na lista, o programa mostre a mensagem 'O filme não consta na lista' apenas uma vez?

Comment: Por favor não duplique suas perguntas. Se a pergunta anterior foi fechada, **[edite-a](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/343670/edit)** esclarecendo o que [foi perguntado nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/343670#comment692301_343670)

Answer (score 2):

Como seu arquivo parece ser separado por ponto-e-vírgula, sugiro que use o módulo `csv` para lê-lo ao invés de dividir linhas manualmente.

Para resolver seu problema, uma das formas mais elegantes é usar o `else` no `for`:

```
import csv

pesquisa = input('Digite o nome do filme: ')

with open('ListaFilmes.txt', newline='') as f:
    cf = csv.DictReader(f, ['nome', 'genero', 'classificacao', 'ano'], delimiter=';')
    for filme in cf:
        if pesquisa in filme['nome']:
            print(filme['nome'], filme['genero'], filme['classificacao'])
            break
    else: # else do for
        print('O filme não consta na lista')
```

Como pode ver, o `else` está alinhado com o `for`, portanto, ele só será executado se o loop do `for` chegar até o fim.

Comment: você poderia colocar para que eu não precise pesquisar o nome completo?por exemplo pesquisei 'o' e apareça  'o senhor dos anéis'

Comment: @JoãoVictorRodrigues só olhar `pesquisa in filme['nome']`... editei a resposta...